# Mapreduce job failed because of container failed

Tags: hadoop

Mapreduce job failed because of container failed with below log.

15/03/21 20:18:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1426295876693_0015 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1426295876693_0015 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1426295876693_0015_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
This token is expired. current time is 1426996344559 found 1426969281613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your cluster is not synced with same system time. Install NTP server. It will fix your issue.